# system cannot find alternative python3 versions on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, updates, python3

I want to update python3 to version 3.9, I ran

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.9
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

. All of which were successful apart from the last command. It gives `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3`.
Can somebody tell me what I am missing?
Thanks!

Comment: If that's really the exact sequence you followed, seems like `sudo apt install python3.9` should have failed: You didn't run another apt update after adding the PPA, so apt wouldn't know of the newly available packages. Check your apt log.

Comment: `python3.9` should never be an alternative.  `python3` should be an alternative.  The command you pasted says you're running config on `python3`, yet it shouldn't complain for `python3.9` unless you typed `python3.9` there.  Are you *sure* you ran the proper update-alternatives command?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I did indeed run another apt upgrade command after adding the ppa. Sorry, I was following instructions of a website and when pasting from the command line I thought it would not be important. @Thomas Ward sorry, that was a typo. It says "no alternatives for python3".

Answer (score 9):

To solve the `error: no alternatives for python3` error message open the terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Comment: This solition not work:
"update-alternatives: --install needs <link> <name> <path> <priority>"

Answer (score 5):

**DON'T** upgrade the default python version of your system. You will break it. Instead, [set up virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to run specific Python versions.

Answer (score 0):

Simple .sh script will solve the problem

```
i=0 ; for p in /usr/bin/python*.* ; do
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python $p $((5 + i))
i=$((i+1))
done
```

Then

```
update-alternatives --config python
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error: no alternatives for python3 error message open the terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo whereis python # for find path to python 3.9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /path/to/python3.9 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```